# Angular + WebAPI - Getting: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token <

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, web-services, release, publish

I feel stuck with an issue that is probably something very simple, but I just cannot figure it out.

I'm writing a small app in Visual Studio 2015 using AngularJS and WebAPI. It all works 100 % correctly in both debug and release mode if I run the app from VS itself. It also works through WebMatrix when I publish the debug version of the app to a folder. But when I publish the release version to a folder and trying to view the app in the browser (using WebMatrix), I receive:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < modernizr:1  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery:1  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bootstrap:1  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angularjs:1  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < modal:1  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app:1
```

It craps out on  tag.

Somewhere I read I need to used the proper syntax in my AngularJS code to make sure the minification is done properly when the app is published. I've done all of that, yet I'm still getting this error. I'm also using ng-strict-di tag and I'm not receiving any errors.

I feel is somehow IIS (Express) + AngularJS related. I've made sure I using html5mode, setting the base href in my initial view, abd implemented routing in web.config. I'm not getting 404 when I refresh the page. I feel I've covered a lot, but it still does not work.

I've search the web up and down and have not been able to find anything that would indicate what needs to be done.

I'm kind of desperate and I'd appreciate any help at this moment.

Please and thanks...

Comment: Looks to me like there's an extra character "<" in your js that's screwing it up for you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. Would the error show when I run the code in VS? It all works just fine in VS.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually figured it out (by pure chance).

It ended up to be that the main page (index) did not like @styles.render and @scripts.render. The whole setup did not like bundling.

As soon as I included the files individually I have configured in the bundles, it all started working.